# Manage user & open ports with Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm getting started with Ansible.

I have few hosts in my `/etc/ansible/hosts`. 
This file and my playbooks are versioned with git.
Members of my team are versioned in git like

```
$cat users/john.json
{
   login: 'john.johnson',
   firstName: 'John',
   lastName : 'Johnson',
   sshPubKey: '....'
}
```

I want to grant access to some users to some machine like:

```
server1 [john, alice, bob]
server2 [john, alice]
server3 [john, bob]
server4 [john]
server5 [john, kevin]
server6 [john, albert, alice]
server7 [john, bob, kevin]
```

I'd also like to have the same approach for open ports like:

```
server1 [22, 80, 443]
server2 [22, 1234]
server3 [22, 1122]
server4 [22]
server5 [22, 1717]
server6 [22, 80, 443]
server7 [22]
```

I don't need help with writing the playbook's tasks (I know how to use the user/ufw module) but I can't find a way to cleanly centralise a per-host configuration with ansible.

The only solution I have for now is to have a `user.yml` and `port.yml` playbook, edit them every time I want to run them for a specific server and run the playbook with a `--limit server1`. It doesn't feel clean and prevent me to have a clear snapshot on git of users' access and open ports for each server.

What would be the clean way to organise this in ansible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the dictionary `servers` (see the abridged version in playbook below) and the JSON files in the directory `users` let's create the dictionary `users` in the first play and use it in the next play. For example

```
- name: Collect data
  hosts: server1:server2:server3

  vars:
    servers:
      server1:
        access: [john, alice, bob]
        ports: [22, 80, 443]
      server2:
        access: [john, alice]
        ports: [22, 1234]
      server3:
        access: [john, bob]
        ports: [22, 1122]

  tasks:

    - block:
        - set_fact:
            servers: "{{ servers }}"
        - set_fact:
            users_list: "{{ servers|json_query('*.access')|flatten|unique }}"
        - set_fact:
            users: "{{ users|default({})|
                       combine({item: lookup('file', 'users/' ~ item ~ '.json')|from_yaml}) }}"
          loop: "{{ users_list }}"
        - debug:
            var: users
      run_once: true

- name: Configure users
  hosts: server1:server2:server3
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg:
          - "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
          - "{{ item }}"
          - "{{ users[item].sshPubKey }}"
      loop: "{{ servers[inventory_hostname].access }}"
```

gives

```
PLAY [Collect data] ***
...
ok: [server1] => 
  users:
    alice:
      firstName: Alice
      lastName: Springs
      login: alice.springs
      sshPubKey: sshPubKey_alice
    bob:
      firstName: Bob
      lastName: Brown
      login: bob.brown
      sshPubKey: sshPubKey_bob
    john:
      firstName: John
      lastName: Johnson
      login: john.johnson
      sshPubKey: sshPubKey_john

PLAY [Configure users] ***
...
ok: [server1] => (item=john) => 
  msg:
  - server1
  - john
  - sshPubKey_john
ok: [server1] => (item=alice) => 
  msg:
  - server1
  - alice
  - sshPubKey_alice
ok: [server1] => (item=bob) => 
  msg:
  - server1
  - bob
  - sshPubKey_bob
ok: [server3] => (item=john) => 
  msg:
  - server3
  - john
  - sshPubKey_john
ok: [server2] => (item=john) => 
  msg:
  - server2
  - john
  - sshPubKey_john
ok: [server3] => (item=bob) => 
  msg:
  - server3
  - bob
  - sshPubKey_bob
ok: [server2] => (item=alice) => 
  msg:
  - server2
  - alice
  - sshPubKey_alice
```

Change the tasks in the play `Configure users` to your needs. In a similar way, it's possible to add a next play `Configure ports`.

Comment: I think all the variables (what you have in vars) could also be fixed in the group_vars / all.yml file, inside the inventory folder. If we talk about centralizing data in git, then I have a good practice storing inventory data separately from ansible playbook code. This is convenient when there are many different playbooks for the same servers (and even more convenient if there is a strict separation of access rights to the code in git).

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this.

Set variables in the inventory:

```
server1 users='["joe", "jane"]'
server2 users='["jane"]'
```

Set the variables in a file in the `host_vars` directory.

Use `include_vars`. Example file contents:

```
"users": {
  "server1": [ "joe", "jane" ],
  "server2": [ "jane" ]
}
```

Load it with `include_vars`. For your task loop (`with_items`) over `users[ansible_hostname]`